# Why does defaultdict default_factory default to None?

Tags: python, defaultdict

You don't have to specify a default factory (but it's the same if you pass `None` explicitly)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> defaultdict()
defaultdict(None, {})
>>> defaultdict(None)
defaultdict(None, {})
```

Why `None` though?  Then we get this thing:

```
>>> dd = defaultdict()
>>> dd[0]
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable  <-- expected behaviour
# KeyError: 0                                   <-- actual behaviour
```

It's even explicitly allowed, because if you try to make a default dict from some other object, `defaultdict(0)` say, there is a failing check

```
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

I thought something like `lambda: None` would be a better default factory.  Why is the `default_factory` optional?  I don't understand the use-case.

Comment: It seems like it works just like regular dict if you leave the argument as None. Seems reasonable.

Comment: This behavior, including the `KeyError`, is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: The documentation answers the question of "what happens when you give `None` to a defaultdict?" but it doesn't answer the question of "why was this behavior implemented in the first place?". I'm pretty puzzled why you would want a defaultdict to ever act like a regular dict. If you want a regular dict, just use `dict`. I believe OP is wondering the same thing.

Comment: This seem to be related: http://bugs.python.org/issue1433928

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When Guido van Rossum [initially proposed a `DefaultDict`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/061169.html) it had a *default value* (unlike the current `defaultdict` which uses a callable rather than a value) that was set during construction and was read-only (also unlike `defaultdict`).

After some discussion [Guidio revised the proposal](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/061261.html).  Here are the relevant highlights:

> Many, many people suggested to use a factory function instead of a
> default value. This is indeed a much better idea (although slightly
> more cumbersome for the simplest cases).
>
> ...
>
> Let's add a generic missing-key handling method to the dict class, as
> well as a default_factory slot initialized to `None`.

> ...

> [T]he default implementation is designed so that we can write
>
> ```
> d = {}
> d.default_factory = list
> ```

The important thing to note is that the new functionality no longer belongs to a subclass.  That means that setting the `default_factory` in the constructor would break existing code.  So by design setting the `default_factory` had to happen after the `dict` was created.  It's initial value is set to `None` and it's now a mutable attribute so that it can be meaningfully overwritten.

After yet more discussion, it was decided that maybe it would be best not to complicate the regular `dict` type with a `defaultdict` specialization.

Steven Bethard then [asked for clarification regarding the constructor](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/061532.html):

> Should default_factory be an argument to the constructor?  The three
> answers I see:
>
> - "No."  I'm not a big fan of this answer.  Since the whole point of creating a defaultdict type is to provide a default, requiring two
>   statements (the constructor call and the default_factory assignment)
>   to initialize such a dictionary seems a little inconvenient.
> - "Yes and it should be followed by all the normal dict constructor arguments."  This is okay, but a few errors, like
>   `defaultdict({1:2})` will pass silently (until you try to use the
>   dict, of course).
> - "Yes and it should be the only constructor argument."  This is my favorite mainly because I think it's simple, and I couldn't think of
>   good examples where I really wanted to do `defaultdict(list, some_dict_or_iterable)` or `defaultdict(list, **some_keyword_args)`.  It's also forward compatible if we need to add some of the dict constructor args in later.

Guido van Rossum [decided that](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/061558.html):

> The defaultdict signature takes an optional positional argument which
> is the default_factory, defaulting to None. The remaining positional
> and all keyword arguments are passed to the dict constructor. IOW:
>
> ```
> d = defaultdict(list, [(1, 2)])
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> d = defaultdict()  
> d.default_factory = list  
> d.update([(1, 2)])
> ```

Note that the expanded code mirrors exactly how it worked when Guido was considering altering `dict` to provide the `defaultdict` behavior.

He also provides [some justifications upthread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/061485.html):

> Even if the default_factory were passed to the constructor, it still
> ought to be a writable attribute so it can be introspected and
> modified. A defaultdict that can't change its default factory after
> its creation is less useful.

Bengt Richter [explains why you might want a mutable default factory](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/061336.html):

> My guess is that realistically default_factory will be used to make
> clean code for filling a dict, and then turning the factory off if
> it's to be passed into unknown contexts. Those contexts can then use
> old code to do as above, or if worth it can temporarily set a factory
> to do some work. Tightly coupled code I guess could pass
> factory-enabled dicts between each other.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the design is intentional in order to make a `defaultdict` instance act like a normal dict, by default, whilst allowing the behaviour to be dynamically modified by simple attribute access later on.

For example:

```
>>> d = defaultdict()
>>> d['k']  # hey I'm just a plain old dict ;) 
KeyError: 'k'
>>> d.default_factory = list
>>> d['L']  # actually, I'm really a defaultdict(list)
[]
>>> d.default_factory = int  # just kidding!  I'm a counter
>>> d['i']
0
>>> d
defaultdict(int, {'L': [], 'i': 0})
```

And we can reset it to something that looks like a vanilla dict (which will again raise `KeyError`), by setting the factory back to `None`.

I have yet to find a pattern where this could be useful, but this usage wouldn't be possible if it was forced to instantiate default dict with one callable positional argument.

Comment: Your guess is correct based on what I could find in python-dev.  See my answer for more.  (I worked way too hard for that useless bit of trivia.)

Comment: It is worth noting that setting the `default_factory` can be useful if the `defaultdict` is created from something other than the usual constructor. For instance, you can do `d = defaultdict.fromkeys(..., 0); d.default_factory = int`.